# Running JNLP as Applet

Tags: java, applet, jnlp

Sorry, Im sort of new to java, and I have a program that runs as a jnlp file, and I was wondering if instead of it downloading the program as a separate window, is it possible to run it as an applet within the browser window?

Comment: could you run your jnlp in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to run an app embedded in a html page instead of a own window? You should have a look at [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html). Instead of extending a `JFrame` you have to extends a `JApplet`. Than you can embed a jar into a html page.

Answer (score 1):

> ... is it possible to run it as an applet within the browser window?

If the browser is configured to launch JNLP files automatically, then yes, it is possible to run them within the browser. Check out [here](http://wiki.wholebraincatalog.org/wiki/Set_up_JNLP_Browser_Association).

Answer (score 0):

If you just run the applet code inside html tags it doesn't work. Run them inside script(javascript) tags.

1. get the jars and class out of jnlp file and put them into applet code.
2. then make that applet runs as java script from your html code.